# In what cases can we use "where" to lead a subordinate clause, when not talking about places?

Tags: word-usage, subordinate-clauses

We can use "Where" to lead subordinate clauses when talking about places.

> A place where people live

Sometimes "where" can also be used for more abstract concepts.

> I missed the part where that's my problem.

My question is, in what cases can "where" be used for abstract concepts or other things that are not places? For example, are the phrases below correct usages of "where"?

> A video where people are dancing with music

> A situation where people live on food stamps

> An opportunity where people can realize their dreams

> An adventure where they lost their lives

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no clear line that tells you where "where" can be used and where it cannot because to speakers of different varieties of English, some of uses sound natural, and to speakers of other varieties, the same uses sound unnatural, or even wrong.

A reasonable test for where we can use "where" is whether it can be replaced by a prepositional phrase, like "in which", "on which", "into which", "onto which" and so on. This tests the grammaticality and semantics, but not the naturalness.

> A place **in which** people live
> I missed the part **because of which** that's my problem.
> A video **in which** people are dancing with music
> A situation **in which** people live on food stamps
> An opportunity **through which??** people can realize their dreams
> An adventure **during which** they lost their lives

The "opportunity" one in particular lies on the line between acceptable and not. Some native speakers would say it's fine, while others would say it's not. I put the question marks there because to my Canadian ear, "through" and "opportunity" do not collocate, but to speakers of other varieties of English, they do collocate.

So, to me, the "...opportunity where..." sentence is awkward and maybe even wrong, but to someone else it might be fine.